# Job to keep a count of XML files

Tags: linux, files

My friend works in a IT company where he is required to keep a count of XML files inside a directory (including subdirectories).

However the count using `ls -LR | grep .xml` or similar takes a lot of time as the count of files is in the millions.

I was thinking what can be a better approach?

Can some kind of background process take care of this, so that whenever there is a new file created or modification time change, it affects the counter (no. of files)?

Answer (score 6):

The daemon you describe could use [inotify](http://www.infoq.com/articles/inotify-linux-file-system-event-monitoring).

But perhaps using `find` and `wc -l` would already be fast enough?

I only ran one quick test, but there is a significant difference between `time ls -lR /mm/|grep -c jpg` (`real  0m2.168s`) and `time find /mm -type f -name \*jpg|wc -l` (`real 0m0.397s`) on my system.  Both return approximately 42000 files, so the difference on larger directories would probably be larger.

(I ran both commands several times to exclude disk caching effects.)

Comment: Thanks for your inputs. find and wc -l takes lots of time, also some kind of notifier is better as the number of files changes are very less, so repetitive find and wc -l doesnt suit mycase.

Comment: Counting lines might take a while. But you can use "-printf ." parameter of find and pipe it to "wc -c" to count the printed dots. That should be faster (see my answer).

Answer (score 3):

Following script will watch a directory indefinitely and print number of '*.xml' files every time the directory content changes.

```
DIR="a_path_to_directory_to_watch"
(echo; inotifywait -m -r -e create -e delete "$DIR" 2> /dev/null) |
    while read; do
        find "$DIR" -name '*.xml' -printf . | wc -c
    done
```