# how to echo find command

Tags: find

For a raspberry backup bash-script I want to log which and how many older backups are deleted.

I use

```
find $backup_path/$HOSTNAME.*.img -mtime +$retention_days -type f -delete
```

to clean.

How do I count and display and log to a file which files are deleted?

Comment: Thank you, I will check the various solutions.

Answer (score 5):

You can use the `-print` option of `find`, to output the files that are deleted, then pipe things to `tee` to write results into a logfile. And finally count the lines of the deleted files and append it in the logfile.

```
find $backup_path/$HOSTNAME.*.img -mtime +$retention_days -type f -delete -print | tee ${LOGFILE} | wc -l | xargs echo "Files deleted:" >> ${LOGFILE}
```

If you want to append new results to the same `${LOGFILE}` you would have to use `tee -a`.

Answer (score 3):

`find` has an `fprint` action that can write the results of the find command to a file. You can then extend your command as:

```
find $backup_path/$HOSTNAME.*.img -mtime +$retention_days -type f -fprint /path/to/log.txt -delete
```

You can then retrieve the file count from the log file, by using `wc`:

```
cat /path/to/log.txt | wc -l
```

If special characters can appear in the results of find, you can use the the `fprint0` option as an alternative. This will write the results to the specified file as null-delimited strings.

To count the items in the resulting file, you can look the options discussed under this question: [Count null delimited items in file](https://unix.stackexchange.com/q/164988/173368).

Comment: Not all implementations of `find` support `fprint`, GNU find does but busybox for example does not.  It's also not mandated by POSIX: https://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/utilities/find.html. And you don't need cat to count number of lines with wc: `wc -l <FILE>` is enough.

Comment: @ArkadiuszDrabczyk Thanks for the information on POSIX find. Regarding the usage of `cat`, I used it so that the output is only a number. `wc` shows the filename  beside the count with the `wc -l file` syntax.

Answer (score 1):

If you may have filenames with newlines in them (`touch /the/path/$'foo\nbar'` to create an example), then you could avoid some confusion by using GNU find's `-fprintf` feature to print the filenames to one logfile and a dot for each filename to a separate logfile. Then the byte count of the dotfile will equal the number of matching files and the filenames themselves will be in a separate file.

```
find "$backup_path"/"$HOSTNAME".*.img -mtime +"$retention_days" -type f \
  -fprintf ./deleted-files '%p\n' \
  -fprintf ./count-files '.' \
  -delete
```

Above, I've specifically placed the two `-fprintf` statements after the previous filtering criteria of `-mtime` and `-type f` and just before the `-delete`, so that they are triggered only when `-delete` would be.

The first new statement prints the file paths to the `./deleted-files` file; the second one prints a dot to `./count-files`. You may browse the deleted-files log for the deleted filenames and use `wc -c < count-files` to report on the total number of deleted files. The filenames are overwritten by `-fprintf` with each run.

Comment: +1, The idea of using dots to count the number of processed files is very clever.

Comment: Thank you, it is! I cannot take any credit for it; I saw it here on U&L and also thought it was clever. [hluk in 2012](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/38486/117549), [slm in 2013](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/101418/117549), [Hauke Laging in 2014](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/116649/117549), [Gilles in 2014](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/123611/117549), [Stéphane in 2015](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/231351/117549), [ilkkachu in 2017](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/376167/117549), and others.

Answer (score 0):

You can use below command to achieve the same

```
find $backup_path/$HOSTNAME.*.img -mtime +$retention_days -type f -exec rm -rvf {} \; >log_file ===> This  will delete and writes to logfile which are the files getting deleted

wc -l log_file===> will display count of files which are deleted
```